# When is control of a Shield Guardian transferred?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Is it when another creature dons the control amulet?
Does the original owner have to expire first?
Is control transferred even if the control amulet is stolen from the previous owner?

The exact scenario is the party has encountered a goblin with a Shield Guardian.  They used 'Command' on the goblin and made it 'give' the amulet to them.  Does control of the Guardian switch to the player immediately when they don the amulet?

Comment: How exactly was it clear with the one-word Command "Give" that the party meant the amulet?

Comment: Many of the sample commands in the spell Command are ambiguous on the face. "Drop" for instance has a specific effect, but could be interpreted as dropping prone or dropping what you are carrying. You could drop a subject, a stitch, a hint, a note, or even just kill a creature. The point is, the DM is there to adjudicate the rules. It appears their DM called this a valid interpretation. Therefore, it was.

Answer (score 11):

### RAW - Immediately

> Every shield guardian has an amulet magically linked to it. A shield guardian can have only one corresponding amulet, ... 
>  ... A shield guardian's solitary focus is to protect the **amulet's wearer**. The amulet's wearer can command the guardian to attack its enemies or to guard the wielder against attack.

As an earlier part of the monsters description describes that the amulet can be given away, traded, etc, it's fairly clear that the previous owner has no command or attunement time (like many magic items in 5th edition). And [a tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/876287007558742016) from Jeremy Crawford confirming no attunement.

<sub>PS - RAI, also yes</sub>

Comment: Follow up question: does this mean if the amulet is removed, the Shield Guardian becomes inert until someone dons it?  Or, it simply continues to follow the last order it was given?

The exact scenario is that the goblin has tossed the amulet over as commanded, but the party member has not yet donned it.  What control does the goblin still retain over the Guardian?

Comment: @user2651044 That feels like a different question: "what happens to a guardian if no one is wearing its amulet?". You could go ahead and ask that as a new question.

Comment: You could ask that as a separate question, but basically the guardian obeys who is wearing the amulet. So if nobody is wearing it, then the guardian stands there doing nothing.

Comment: @user2651044 In my opinion "holds in their possession" is the same as "donning", for this particular case. However, I agree with the previous two that "does a shield guardian become inert of no one possesses the amulet?" is a separate question.

Comment: you could add this crawford tweet if you wanted to make it super official: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/876287007558742016

Answer (score 6):

### Yes.

Pertinent text, emphasis mine.

> The Shield Guardian is magically bound to an Amulet. As long as the Guardian and its Amulet are on the same plane of existence, the **amulet's wearer** can telepathically call the Guardian to travel to it, and the Guardian knows the distance and direction to the Amulet.

Nothing about Shield Guardian says anything about requiring attunement or if the amulet leaves your possession, so the Guardian protects whoever wears the amulet.

This is also backed up [in a tweet](http://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/876287007558742016) by Crawford

Comment: good God, our answers are similar.

Comment: LOL yeah. I just typed faster.

Comment: you could add this crawford tweet if you wanted to make it super official: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/876287007558742016

Answer (score 3):

## It obeys whoever is wearing the amulet:

From the description for a shield guardian (emphasis mine):

> A shield guardian's solitary focus is to protect the amulet's *wearer.* The amulet's *wearer* can command the guardian to attack its enemies or to guard the wielder against attack

Both the Bound trait and the Spell Storing trait also reference the amulet's wearer.